# How to move a view to a dialog in andorid

Tags: android, android-view

I have a linear layout that the user can insert elements to it dynamically to send to the server, and I plan to have a confirmation dialog after that user clicks the send button. In the dialog I want to show the layout once again. Can I somehow clone or move the view to the new dialog and not make it again.

Comment: You can set a custom layout for a Dialog. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout

Answer (score 1):

```
    ViewGroup viewRoot =  (ViewGroup)LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog_example, null);
    //you can measure the width of viewRoot,if the width is specified
    int measuredWidth = DimenUtil.getMeasuredWidth(viewRoot);
    int measuredHeight = DimenUtil.getMeasuredHeight(viewRoot);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

/**
 You should execute statement before setContentView(int layout),or an AndroidRuntimeException will be occurred ,because requestFeature() must be called before adding content, I also confused about this reason 
**/

```
    dialog.show();
    dialog.setContentView(viewRoot);
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setGravity(gravity);
    window.setLayout(measuredWidth, measuredHeight);
```